# How can I make a bootable clone of one SSD to another SSD?

Tags: windows-7, clone

Is it possible to clone a SSD with Windows 7 installed onto another SSD?

I want to do this so I can then choose between the 2 SSDs as to which I want to boot.

Comment: I believe that this type of question has been answered in one form or another several times.  Have you taken a look at the archives?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to clone the drives, then [GParted](http://gparted.org/) to adjust the "bootable" flags of the devices (or you could just change the boot order in BIOS).

Comment: Could also modify the bootloader to display both operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linux live CD laying around you can [use DD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/).
It's a powerful command-line utility for reading and writing binary files.

I'm a little confused as to why you want to boot a copy of the same operating system off of two different SSD's-- unless you're trying to create a separate fallback installation. If you want to see a menu and be able to choose which one to boot, you'll need to edit the Boot tab of your System Configuration (accessible from the start menu or control panel)

Comment: Just purchased a bigger SSD would be a good reason :D

Comment: Definitely, but if I was doing that, I would want to fully migrate and use the other SSD for something else, such as a dualboot Linux setup. Seems like the original question implies a desire for two copies of Win7 however.

Answer (score 0):

What is the brand of SSD ? I am using Samsung and they provide an application called "[Samsung Data Migration](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html)" which allows cloning existing system drive to another SSD.

Most of the time SSD vendors provide their own utility to clone existing system.