# How to clone an freezed SSD to another SSD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, freeze, clone

I have a system running Windows 7 OS, with many programs. It's frozen by deep freeze. The old SSD is 120GB and the new one is 120GB as well. I tried a [raw copy program](http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool/) to clone it. But it didn't clone (I used, a third hard for hosting the OS). BTW, I want to clone the SSD to another HDD or SDD. I've studied [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/603682/how-can-i-make-a-bootable-clone-of-one-ssd-to-another-ssd) and some related question. But I still have the problem.

Comment: The uncertainty of what you do and don't know plus the numerous grammatical mistakes makes this question extremely hard to follow.  You should confirm (one way or another) everything you do and don't know

Comment: I can not answer find the answer button to answer this question.My problem is solved with Clonezilla. I got another problem during the cloning process. Both SSD devices were not same in a number of the sector. Actually, the target was smaller for just some number of sectors.

Comment: Question was closed.  Feel free to improve the quality of the question so it can be reopened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try downloading a copy of Linux (mint or ubuntu etc) then burn it to a CD/DVD or create a USB bootable flash stick. After booting to Linux you could open a terminal window and run the command dd if=/dev/*sourceharddrive* of=/dev/*destinationharddrive* where *sourceharddrive* and *destinationharddrive* represent the drive's ID in the system, usually sda or sdb etc.

if you are unable to understand Linux or how to run a terminal, you could try using a program like HexWorkshop to copy the sectors from one drive to the other. The program you used may be buggy or flawed in some way.

Comment: Actually, I'm familiar with ubuntu. But, this time I can not install. Is it a big problrm to write the image of Clonezilla to a CD with programs such as Nero, Ashampoo, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove Deep Freeze first. If you contact support they have a file that you can replace that will stop Deep Freeze from loading. Then you can remove Deep Freeze by running the installation.
At the same time, you could simply just run the installer and that same installer will uninstall Deep Freeze. If the computer can still connect to the Enterprise console then you can remove Deep Freeze from there.
Regardless or, your question should be how to remove Deep Freeze rather than how to clone the drive. If you were to clone it bit by bit (clonezilla, or DD) you would end up with a system with Deep Freeze in the other end too, and that is definitively something that Faronics does not support (for example if you are running images they recommend to remove Deep Freeze first)

Comment: Can I use Clonezilla and do not remove deep freez?